# Bufferedreader blocks thread but adding in if(br.ready()) stops disconnect check

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, bufferedreader

Im making a chat server/client. I have a BufferedReader reading my inputstream from a socket, and when it .readLine() it blocks. I added in if(BufferedReader.ready()) but that means I can no longer detect disconnected clients, as if i did add in else System.out.println("Client disconnected") then whenever the client user does not send a message for more than a couple of milliseconds it presumes the user is dissconnected.
How do I get out of this?
code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SpeechHandler implements Runnable {

public SpeechHandler (BufferedReader r, ServerMain sm, Socket soc) {

    try {

    boolean connected = true;

    while (connected) {

        try {

            String text = null;

            text = r.readLine();

            if (!text.equals(null)) {

                sm.tellAll(text);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Client " + soc.getInetAddress() + " has disconnected");
            sm.removeStream(soc.getInputStream());
            sm.removeStream(soc.getOutputStream());
            e.printStackTrace();
            connected = false;

        }

    }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

@Override
public void run () {



}
```

}

**Found Answer** The problem was not the reader blocking the thread, but the fact that all the code was written in the constructor, not the run() method, as that meant the other thread waited for the constructor to complete before moving on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a BufferedReader reading my inputstream from a socket, and when it .readLine() it blocks.

Correct. That is the specified behaviour.

> I added in if(BufferedReader.ready()) but that means I can no longer detect disconnected clients

Correct. There are few if any correct uses of `ready(),` and this isn't one of them.

> then whenever the client user does not send a message for more than a couple of milliseconds it presumes the user is dissconnected.

That's a bug in your code. Don't 'presume' after 'a couple of milliseconds'.

> How do I get out of this?

You are using blocking I/O. You are expected to dedicate a thread to reading from the socket, and detecting end of stream or an exception to indicate peer disconnection.

Comment: The thing is, I have three other threads, one that is created whenever a client joins to handle its connection request (which in turn creates this thread) one to deal with any newly detected clients (which in turn creates the connection request thread) and one which is the main thread to handle input from the user (which starts of the newly detected client thread), but all are blocked when it comes to the `BufferedReader.readLine()`

Comment: @dodo No they aren't. Only the thread that is calling `readLine()` blocks. If they are all calling `readLine()` on the same socket there is something seriously wrong with your code, and your design.